# How long will side-quests last for?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

I've found myself in a bit of a pickle...I hopped aboard a helicopter ride after a certain quest.  Early game spoiler:

> It's the helicopter ride you take after you disable the signaling device that's been hacking into your company's computers.

I had a few side-quests that weren't complete yet before hopping onto the helicopter.  Are they still going to be completeable after I return?  Are there any side-quests that 'expire' if not done in enough time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some quests will not be available as there are some parts where you will not return to that location, so if you haven't completed them - you won't get another chance.  There aren't any that have a specific time limit on them (other than you may need to complete certain aspects quickly).

> You will return to Detroit, so any additional sub-quests will be available which don't involve the main plotline.  However you will not always return 'home' so I recommend just doing them ASAP

Comment: Are any of those parts in the first area of the game?  I.E., Detroit?

Comment: It's incredibly difficult to be specific without totally ruining the game for either you or others.  I've put some info in my original post with a spoiler tag.

Answer (score 0):

During my play trough I did all the quests I came across, found no real timed side quests, mostly dialogue/action based (outcome decided through action), but that is what the game is based upon. Yes, there is some side quests that will expire after some events, either the person dies, switch location or simply replace it with another quest. Minor spoiler, a key person *will* die. But whom you shall see for yourself. You should be warned if you leave the current zone and still have quests to do, but I believe this was those you already knew of, but hadn't completed.